# Basis for an eigenstate

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

I have a matrix $$B= \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&0&0 \\
    0&0&1 \\
    0&1&0
 \end{bmatrix}$$

with two eigenvalues $\lambda=-1$ with eigenvector **u**=$(0,-1,1)$ and the double eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ to which corresponds the eigenspace $S_2$ given by $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:y-z=0$

**My question is:**

How can I find a basis of the eigenspace $S_2$?

In general, is a basis of a degenerate eigenspace given by its eigenvectors that are equal in number to the degeneracy and are linearly independent?

Could you please show me how linear independence is required?

I would do this:

One eigenstate can be $(2,1,1)$ and the other eigenstate $(0,1,1)$, now what about the independence?

and generally speaking, how do you find the basis of an eigenspace?

Comment: If you know how to compute a kernel then just apply the definition : $S_2$ is the kernel of $B-I_3$

Comment: The proposed duplicate target concerns how to find the basis for a subspace defined by a first degree homogeneous polynomial condition on components.  With a little effort that technique could be applied here, but it would be worth explaining how.  Here we need (for eigenvalue $1$) a basis for solutions to $Bv = v$  Alternatively use elimination to find a basis for solutions to $(B-I)v = 0$ as @Lelouch suggests.

Answer (score 0):

$y-z=0$ means $y=z$ and $x$ is free since we have no condition on it, therefore the vectors inside $S_2$ have shape $(x,y,y)=x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,1)$. Since $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are independent then these two vectors are your basis.

Comment: is $(-2,1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ also a basis?

Comment: @Salmone If they both are in the eigenspace and are linearly independent, yes. Can you verify that ?

Comment: Yes, they both are in the eigenspace and linearly independent. So the general rule is: let $n$ be the degeneracy of the eigenspace, if I want to find a basis I need $n$ eigenvectors inside that eigenspace which are linearly independent, right? So the basis are infinite?